# How to Save data and pass data between activities

Tags: android, key

I have two activities, First One will display user favorite values if set if not set i"ll call second activity set the fav values. When the fav values are set when i run the app next time i should read the data from key value set and display those values in the first activity

Now i can set the key value and read it and show it in the same activity but when i go back or re launch the app the data stored in key value set is not read,
can any one help me with what i am missing here,
or is there any simple way to achieve this.

Comment: did u tried passing data via intent?

Comment: use `SharedPreference` to store data and use `putExtra` for passing data between activities

Comment: use preferences or database my friend

Comment: Check this out.
[Different ways to pass data between activity][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android

Answer (score 1):

for that you must need to implement  `SharedPreference` in your project..
googling for `SharedPreferences` demo

Answer (score 1):

Set vlaues as:

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
Editor edit = pref.edit();
edit.putBoolean("news_icon_flag", true);
edit.putString("key","value");
edit.commit();
```

Then get these values whereever needed in any activity as follows:

```
pref.getString("key","defaultvalue");
```

Answer (score 1):

for storing data into android see [official Doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

in your case you may use  `SharedPreference`

when you are in firstActivity, pass value to your second activty like this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivty.this, SecondActivity.class);
 intent.putextra("key","value");
 startActivity(intent);
```

while doing this you are able to pass velue in secondActivity now you are in second activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String = intent.getStringExtra("key");

 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("key", value);
 editor.commit();
```

for retrieving data from `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("key", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use intents to pass data between activites.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(current.this, Destination_activity.class);
intent.putextra("keyName","value");
startActivity(intent);
```

In your destination activity use this to get the "value" sent

```
 String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("keyName");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the data from second activity to first activity you have to set data in 
Intent Bundle and listen it in onActivityForResult().

When you launch your second activity from fists activity do it like:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
```

And override method in same activity:-

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            String data = data.getStringExtra("fav");;
            SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

           Editor edit = pref.edit();
           edit.putString("favourities", data);  //edit.putString("key","value");
           edit.commit();
           //More about SharedPref you can find [here][1]
        }
    }
```

and in your second activity when you set your data do like:-

```
String favourities=editText1.getText().toString();  
                Intent intent=new Intent();  
                intent.putExtra("fav", favourities);  

                setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);  

                finish();//finishing activity
```

More about onActivityForResult you can find [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example)

And when next time you launch your app you can get your data from SharedPref by calling

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String fav= pref.getString("favourities", null);
```